# How to write this as a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was solving differential equations problems from Mary Boas book, and there was a problem that I couldn't write it as a differential equation

**Solve the equation for the rate of growth of bacteria if the rate of increase is proportional to the number present but the population is being reduced at a constant
rate by the removal of bacteria for experimental purposes.**

How can I add the removal rate to my differential equation (I write the increase rate as $$\dfrac{dN}{dt} = KN(t)$$where $K$ is a constant, and $N(t)$ is the number of bacteria at any time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We should add the term for the removal at a constant rate $K_2>0$ that is

> $$\dfrac{dN(t)}{dt} = KN(t)-K_2 $$

Comment: At the end of the book, the final answer is $N = N_0e^{Kt}-(R/K)(e^{Kt}-1)$, however, if I just add it like that I get $N = \frac{N_0e^{Kt}+R}{K}$

Comment: You also need to adjust for the initial conditions $N(0)=N_0$, check that!

Comment: Your solution is not compatible with the initial condition. If you show your derivation I’ll take a look to it.

Comment: It does work for this boundary condition, THANK YOU.

Comment: @DavidScott You are welcome! Well done, Bye.